# Algorithm for Calendar Calculation

Tags: algorithm, logic

One of the interview question..

If

```
1st january 2006 --> Sunday
```

Then

```
1st january 2010 --> ???
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: Hint: work out how many days occur in four years, assuming they *don't* skip a leap year due to the "divisible by 100" rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 1 day for each non-leap year and 2 days for each leap year whatever comes that value mod 7.And finally add that amount of days with the given day.
for eg.

```
2007=1 day

2008=2 days

2009=1 day

2010=1 day
```

so total `5` days
and `5 % 7=5`
Add `5` days in sunday,so you will get `Friday`

Answer (score 0):

Year 2006 is not a leap year, it has 365 days.

Year 2007 has 365 days.

Year 2008 is a leap year, it has 366 days.

Year 2009, 365 days.

So there're 365+365+366+365==1461 days different of the two dates.

One week has 7 days, and 1461 mod 7 is 5, 5 days after Sunday is Friday.

So the answer is Friday.